# Unpin or remove star on Gmail Message using the api

Tags: gmail-api

I am trying to update a message in gmail to remove the pin and I thought I could do it using labels. But I am getting a bad request error.

Anyone aware of a way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very hard to say where the issue is without you sharing your code and the exact error message you're getting but to remove a star from a message, you'd use [messages.modify()](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/modify) with a body having the `removeMessageLabelIds` list and `STARRED` as the label to remove. I haven't tested pinning but I believe that'd be removing the `INBOX` label.

Comment: I was using the messages.modify() method and STARRED does work. PINNED however does not appear in the list of labels from the api and returns the following error when the label is removed.

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalidArgument",
    "message": "Invalid label: PINNED"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid label: PINNED"
 }
}

I will try the INBOX label

Comment: I can confirm that removing the INBOX label did remove the pin. Adding the INBOX label back does not restore the pin. Any idea how to pin something?

Comment: I played with this too, and I have found no direct access to control pinning in Google Inbox.  Pinning a thread in the UI adds the INBOX label to every message in the thread.  The UI has a popup that says "Pinning to the Inbox".  Unpinning in the UI caused the INBOX label to be removed (if the thread was already checked "Done").  But, interestingly, the thread could still be "archived" from within the Gmail web interface (not Google Inbox), which seemed to remove a label called "Inbox" shown there o.O

Comment: I also found no way to programmatically determine if a message is PINNED

Answer (score 0):

**Tl;DR:** If you find this thread because you want to disable pinning in Google Inbox (maybe because you dislike that snoozed emails automatically get pinned, breaking them out of bundles), don't try to solve that with the Gmail API. Maybe try [this TamperMonkey user script](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/32368-google-inbox-unpinner) instead.

**Detail:**

I want to add a dire warning for anyone who finds this thread while trying to do what I just wasted a lot of hours on:

If you dislike that snoozed emails get pinned when they un-snooze, don't try to solve this with the Gmail API. You might know that whether an email is in the inbox (versus being archived) is [handled by an INBOX label](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/labels), and you might know that you can subscribe to [push notifications](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push) about a mailbox.

So you read Paul McManus's comment above that mentions that removing and re-adding the INBOX label with the Gmail API un-pins your messages. You put it together and think it'll solve your problem - you'll subscribe to push notifications about mailbox changes, then use [history/list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/history/list) to find recent messages that gained the INBOX label, and you'll use [message/modify](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/modify) to remove and re-add the INBOX label.

The problem is that history/list doesn't show changes from emails becoming un-snoozed (even though they gained the INBOX label). So you won't know which message to un-pin.

After discovering that, I thought through the problem again and realized that a [user script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Userscript) that calls the click event on un-pin buttons would also solve the problem, and that's just a few lines of Javascript. [You can get it here](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/32368-google-inbox-unpinner). The only problem is that it won't work on your phone.

Answer (score 0):

What I did to solve the same problem was.

1. Use the [Threads.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/list) API with a query (q param) of is:pinned to get all threads that were "pinned".
2. Loop through those threads and use the [Threads.modify](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/modify) API to first removeLableIds of "Inbox" then addLabelIds to add Inbox back.  This removed the pin from the thread and kept it sorted in my Inbox the way I wanted it.

Of course every time you snooze an email with Google's Inbox, you'll have to run the same script again.  I haven't figured out the best way to automate that yet, but potentially using push notification for inbox changes could do it.